# join 2 models through another model which they have a foreign key to it

Tags: python, django, orm, outer-join

i have 3 models temp1,temp2,temp3 which temp1 and temp2 have foreign keys to temp3.id. that means that temp1 and temp2 are related through temp3.id.

```
 Class temp1(models.Model):
    temp3 = models.ForeignKey('temp3', verbose_name=u"temp3", null=True, blank=True)
    i_y = models.IntegerField('i_Y',null=True, blank=True)
    iq = models.FloatField('IQ', null=True, blank=True)



class temp2(models.Model):
    temp3 = models.ForeignKey('temp3', verbose_name=u"temp3", null=True, blank=True)
    q_y = models.IntegerField('Y', null=True, blank=True)
    eq = models.IntegerField('EQ', null=True, blank=True)
    q_c = models.CharField('category', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)


class temp3(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
```

how can i do full outer join on temp1 and temp2 models using django ORM?
Indeed i want to do an sql query like this with Django ORM:

```
select temp3.title, temp1.i_y, temp1.iq, temp2.eq,temp2.q_c, temp2.q_y from (select temp1.i_y, temp1.iq, temp1.temp3_id AS first_table_id,temp2.temp3_id AS second_table_id,temp2.eq, temp2.q_c, temp2.q_y from temp1 full outer join temp2 on (temp1.temp3_id = temp2.temp3_id AND temp1.i_y = temp2.q_y)) AS t left outer join temp3 (t.first_table_id = temp3.id OR t.second_table_id = temp3.id)
```

I should mention that for each row of temp3, there are multiple rows on temp1 and temp2 models in db and i aim to retrieve all rows which are satisfied by the join conditions

Comment: Why dont you use ManyToManyFields with the though parameter. It would be easier for use because django provides many querysets in its ORM by default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your related temp3, and then get a set of all temp2 referring to this temp3:

```
t1 = temp1.objects.first()
t3 = t1.temp3
t2_set = t3.temp2_set.all()
```

Or, in one Line:

```
t2_set = temp1.objects.first().temp3.temp2_set.all()
```

But as Michael said, you should use the Many2Many Field if its possible.

Comment: what does to do first() function?

Comment: first function just takes the first object from database. replace it with the method you need, for example all() for the full list, or get(key=value).